# Detecting communities on a social network with python

Tags: python, facebook, social-networking, networkx

I am trying to analyse a social network (basically, friends of a facebook user) with python. My main goal is to detect the social circles of the network. So far i tried to use networkx, but I couldn't understand how it can detect communities. Is there a way, with netowrkx or with another package, to solve this problem? thank you!

Comment: This questions is a bit broad, networkx has many algoriths such as `find_cliques` and `closeness_centrality`, you need to try or do more research as there are many definitions of what a community are

Answer (score 1):

Recommend to use igraph which has many community detection algorithms.